# Google Docs Identify Spreadsheet or Form

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to identify whether document is Spreadsheet or Form in Google Documents using ASP.net?

Comment: Be more specific. What API are you using? What are you starting with? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm using Google.GData Dll's to get the document list.. I got the code through Google Documents List API

Answer (score 0):

The MIME type is the best way to detect the native Google document format:

- Google Doc
  application/vnd.google-apps.document
- Google Spreadsheet
  application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
- Google Form
  application/vnd.google-apps.form
- Google Presentation
  application/vnd.google-apps.presentation
- Google Drawing
  application/vnd.google-apps.drawing

Ref: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#managing_archives_of_documents_and_files